# Cast IP address as string to INSERT into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, powershell, insert, sql-server-2012

If I run the following on SQL Server 2012, it works

```
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM dbo.Computers
                 WHERE Computer_ID = 'A1E8AC100AFB160500BAD934ACD97536')
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Computers(Date_of_Record, Computer_Name, IP_Address, Operating_System, Agent_Version, BIOS_Version, Computer_ID)
    VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'LPB0FLYX', '10.10.10.10', 'Windows 7 Enterprise Edition', '12.1.2015.2015', 'LENOVO - 6040000 Phoenix BIOS SC-T v2.2', 'A1E8AC100AFB160500BAD934ACD97536')
  END
END
```

However, if I run the following in Powershell (where `$k[1]` has the value 10.10.10.10), it does not work

```
$SQL_UPDATE = "BEGIN
                      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM dbo.Computers
                                     WHERE Computer_ID = $k[5])
                      BEGIN
                          INSERT INTO dbo.Computers(Date_of_Record, Computer_Name, IP_Address, Operating_System, Agent_Version, BIOS_Version, Computer_ID)
                          VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), $k[0], $k[1], $k[2], $k[3], $k[4], $k[5])
                      END
                  END
```

This is the structure of the table I created

[image]

How to cast `$k[1]` to a string so in effect I am passing in '10.10.10.10'

EDIT

Here is echo of $SQL_UPDATE

```
BEGIN
                      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM dbo.Computers
                                     WHERE Computer_ID = 9D2838890AFB16050170A8AEE4F15517)
                      BEGIN
                          INSERT INTO dbo.Computers(Date_of_Record, Computer_Name, IP_Address, Operating_System, Agent_Version, BIOS_Version, Computer_ID)
                          VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), LMG0033SZ, 10.10.10.10, Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, 12.1.4013.4013, LENOVO - 1180 LENOVO BIOS Rev: FNKT24A 0.0, 9D2838890AFB16050170A8AEE4F15517)
                      END
                  END
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near 'D2838890AFB16050170A8AEE4F15517'.
Incorrect syntax near '.194'."
At D:\Script\unknowns.ps1:259 char:5
+     $cmd_update.executenonquery()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Comment: I suspect that you're missing single quotes in the generated query. Could you echo the resulting content of $SQL_UPDATE and add to the question?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I updated question. How to add single quotes?

Comment: I suspect it's as easy as `VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), '$k[0]', '$k[1]', '$k[2]', '$k[3]', '$k[4]', '$k[5]')`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson --- You solved my issue!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you should post this as an Answer so the question doesn't remain "unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing quotes around your strings in the generated SQL.

If you have control over the values you want to include (ie so that they don't contain single quotes), you can simply add quotes to the string;

```
...
VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), '$k[0]', '$k[1]', '$k[2]', '$k[3]', '$k[4]', '$k[5]')
...
```